# Removing a detached instance error on delete

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

When I am trying to delete below Customer object from a REST controller getting ***"Removing a detached instance"*** exception.

**LOG:**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Removing a detached instance com.test.model.Customer#1750; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance com.test.model.Customer#1750
```

**Domain:**

```
@Entity
public class Customer{

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY_ID", nullable=false)
private Country country;

// other stuff with getters/setters

}
```

**REST Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/shop/services/customers")
public class CustomerRESTController {

   /**
     * Deletes a customer
     */
    @RequestMapping( value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable Long id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        Customer customer = customerService.getById(id);
        if(customer != null){
            customerService.delete(customer);
        }else{
            response.sendError(503, "No Customer found for ID : " + id);
        }
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

I am getting Customer object from Data Base, however still hibernate complaining. 
Any suggestion??

Comment: Can you show the code for `customerService`?

Comment: Sure....here it is:                         `@Service("customerService")
public class CustomerServiceImpl{
 public Customer getById(Long id) {
   return customerDAO.getById(id);  
 }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entity is detached in the current session (or better transaction). Since you are inside Spring it is quite common that you are using a [Java Transaction Service (JTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_transaction_service) for transaction behaviour. With such Hibernate clears the persistence context automatically after commit (as it does when used as a JPA solution).

Normally Hibernate does not clear the persistence context of the session so your entities normally are not detached after commit. (which is unsafe in a distributed environment but save if you use only Hibernate to access the database and use a distributed cache like Ehcache).

Solution: `session.merge(object)` to reattach your entity to the persistence context of the current session object.

It is not actually a merge but rather a reattached and if Hibernate is unsure if the current state of the entity is reflecting the proper database cache it will reload the entity. (And add special behaviour in case of the presents of a version property(@Version)).

By the way the documentation of Hibernate states:

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it will be loaded.

**Update**

After seeing your code this looks like a transactional problem. Please check if your customerService.getById(id) and customerService.delete(customer) service calls result in transaction commits. You need to place both within the very same transaction.

One thing you can also do which also solve your issue is:

```
public void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable Long id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    boolean wasDeleted = customerService.delete(id);
    if(!wasDeleted)
        response.sendError(503, "No Customer found for ID : " + id);
    }
}
```

This way you do not need two service calls. It is actually untypically to use hibernate entities in high level service calls (but that might differ for different architectures. I do not utilize Spring that much).

Comment: Thanks!...Your suggestion is working. I moved retrieve and delete logic from controller to a single Service method.